# Dropdown menu not working properly on IE8

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, menu, joomla3.1

I'm trying to make this dropdown menu functional... but I almost give up trying to make it works on IE8, though it works on IE7...

```
http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/5137/
```

The problem is that on IE8 when the dropdown menu is displayed, it seems to be like... invisible? I move the mouse over it and I can see the links appearing in the status bar, but nothing else.

Image of the problem:
http://tinypic.com/r/2uqdpqd/5

I think the problem is related to some inherited style from bootstrap, as out of it, it seems to work.

I've tried jQuery to solve the problem, forcing the children ul to be shown as block once the mouse move over the parent li, but it's not what I'm looking for.

Also I had to remove some of the styles that Joomla was trying to include in the navigator block.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
if (!jQuery("html").hasClass()) {
    // dropdown
    jQuery('.parent').addClass('has-sub');
    jQuery('.cssmenu > ul').removeClass();
    jQuery('.cssmenu ul li > ul').removeClass();
    jQuery('.cssmenu ul li > ul').addClass('unstyled');
};});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have too much time to go through your example, but I added the following code into your CSS and it seems to be working fine now. Please let me know if it worked for you too.

```
.cssmenu ul li:hover > ul {
display:block;
}
```

Comment: I had already tried it without success, I didn't know why, but after reading your answer I decided to give it a try again, added **!important** and it works!.

Looks like the bootstrap of Joomla is working different to my vanilla bootstrap project.

Comment: OK. I made it work without using `!important`... the problem was just this CSS:  
`filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff9812', endColorstr='#e17310', GradientType=0);`  
  
  
Looks like IE8 stops the CSS execution when reaching "filter". Weird... that simple line was driving me crazy.  

Thanks! ;)